# How to fix undefined modules error in Verilog? (Nandland)

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am trying to run a synthesis on the Verilog code that I copied line-for-line from two different Nandland tutorials:

[Seven Segment Display](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iT9MVuIZFJ8&list=PLnAoag7Ew-vr1M98Q5K2kLHxFQ5l0DU3B&index=8)

[UART Receiver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vh0KdoXaVgU&list=PLnAoag7Ew-vr1M98Q5K2kLHxFQ5l0DU3B&index=10&t=1214s)

Every time I run a synthesis on each project's respective code, I get an error that a module is "undefined.

[image: Skip to 13:46 of "Seven Segment Display" Project]

Skip to 13:46 of "Seven Segment Display" Project. Its respective error is: Reference to undefined module Binary_To_7Segment

[image: Skip to 22:29 of "UART Receiver" Project]

Skip to 22:29 of "UART Receiver" Project. Its respective error is: Reference to undefined module UART_RX

Has anyone else experienced this issue before? If so, how can it be fixed?

Comment: Please include a list of files you are trying to synthesize, and the name of the top level module for each project.   Modify the post don't add the list in the comments.  Add information to support the question.  What synthesis tool are you using?